# Problems concerning R and R[x]

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

A few questions relevant formally,  but quite different in nature:

From now on, let R denote a ring.

1. If R is a UFD , is R[x] also a UFD?
2. If R is Noetherian, is R[x] also Noetherian?
3. If R is a PID, is R[x] also a PID?

**4. If R is an Artin ring, is R[x] also an Artin ring?**

For 1, we all know it's Gauss's lemma.

For 2, we all know it's Hilbert's basis theorem.

For 3, we all know that in Z[x], the ideal (2,x) is not a principal ideal, so the answer is negative.

But what about 4?

Answer (score 12):

The answer to 4 is "no." If $R$ is an Artin ring, then it is Noetherian of Krull dimension zero. It follows from dimension theory that $R[X]$ is Noetherian of dimension one, i.e., not every prime ideal in $R[X]$ is maximal, so $R[X]$ can't be Artin.

Comment: Another really easy way to see that $R[X]$ fails to be Artin is the descending chain $(X)\supseteq (X^2)\supseteq\cdots$.

Comment: ...assuming $0 \neq 1$ :)

Answer (score 7):

Good argument.
But let's give a down-to-earth counterexample:

Let $R$ be a field.  Then consider
$$(x)\supset (x^2)\supset(x^3)\supset\ldots.$$
This is a descending chain of ideals that doesn't become stationary so $R[X]$ is not Artin.

Comment: Yes, I realized this and posted a comment. 

Comment: Hm, sorry. I didn't see it early enough. *g*

Comment: Don't worry about it. 

Comment: Note that one can give a very similar proof of fact that if integral domain is an artinian ring then it is a field (this also follows from consideration involving dimension).